# Restoring wpa_supplicant.conf [root]

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, restore, password, 5.1-lollipop

I have a rooted Nexus 5 (Lollipop 5.1) which just decided to restart itself and clear out my saved WiFi passwords!

Luckily I make regular manual backups of the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file from `/data/misc/wifi` to `/sdcard`.

However I am trying to restore this file so that the networks appear again under Wifi > Saved Networks but I am having no luck!

I have tried to copy the file from `/sdcard` to `/data/misc/wifi` and `/system/etc/wifi` (even though I'm pretty sure it's the one in `/data` that Android uses) using ES File Explorer. The networks do not show up and after restarting the phone, the file in `/data` resets itself and the one in `/system` is remains.

I have also tried copying the file using Terminal Emulator and also running `chown` on the file in `/data` but this also hasn't worked.

Any ideas as to why Android doesn't accept the restored file?

Comment: My guess would be that it is loaded into RAM before you can copy it over, and then saved back from RAM on shutdown.  Possibly you could create an update.zip and flash it from Recovery.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was necessary to change the owner and group of the file to `wifi`:

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
chown wifi:wifi /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
ls -la /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
-rw-rw---- wifi     wifi         2343 2016-07-11 10:31 wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Note: you need a rooted device to do that.