# Pushing wpa_supplicant.conf through adb breaks wifi even with no changes to the file

Tags: wi-fi, adb, system

So I have an issue with very high packet loss on M and above so I know it's something to do with android and not the physical phone. I'm trying to modify wpa_supplicantl.conf but even if I pull it from my phone then push the unmodified file, wifi won't work after the next reboot until I delete the file and it's regenerated, anyone know why this is happening?

Note: I forgot to say, I've checked permissions and it's not an issue with them, it's 0660 before and 0660 after.

Comment: Looking at this with some interest, as I've experienced it myself. Have you checked ownership as well (see [Restoring wpa_supplicant.conf](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/103338/16575))? Check the original ownership of the system created file before; the answer linked uses `chown wifi:wifi`, other places mention `system:wifi`. Not tried myself (no time to play with that currently), so please report if it works for you and I make it an answer if it does.

Comment: Yeah, that work

Comment: Glad to read, thanks for the feedback! Made this an answer that so you can "accept" it – and I know what to take care of next time I want to use this approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've checked ownership as well (see [Restoring wpa_supplicant.conf](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/103338/16575))? Check the original ownership of the system created file before; the answer linked uses `chown wifi:wifi`, other places mention `system:wifi`.